# Including MATLAB in html

Tags: html, matlab

I wrote a Matlab program that analyzes an image and plots a route between a starting point and end point on the image while avoiding all obstacles in between. I am now creating a website to showcase some of my projects and this project is one I would like to include. My question is, how could I include this Matlab function into my website?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to include? The source code or the actual program?

Comment: I want to include the actual program. Essentially I want someone visiting my website to be able to draw their own picture of the obstacle course, then use my matlab program to calculate the quickest route and draw the path, all on the website.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/desktop-web-deployment/deploying-code-web-application.html

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the `publish` function.